# Setting router queryParams in angular 2 do not work

Tags: javascript, angular, router, angular-routing

I try to pass an Arry to router queryParams,but it doesn't work every time.

this is my code :

```
clickOrg(event) {
  if (this.idLists[this.idLists.length - 1] != event.id) {
    this.idLists.push(event.id);
    this.type = event.type;
    console.log (this.idLists)
    this.router.navigate(['userManage'], { queryParams: {idLists:this.idLists,type:this.type} });
  }
}
```

the result of the log (this.idLists) is right
[image]

but the router's queryParams didn't update[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also have a problem with queryParams.They were working for a few time. But suddenly stopped.

I have made temporary solution for that.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`${this.env.getLoginUrl()}?returnUrl=${state.url}`);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745224/angular-2-router-queryparams-are-not-added-into-url/48745491#48745491