# Angular 2 router queryParams are not added into url

Tags: angular, router, query-string

I have an auth guard, which protects somes pages of my web-app. During the redirect i wanted to add queryParams to my url to allow user to come back to the site he want to pass. Code below was working for a few time. Today i realised that queryParms are not present in the url

```
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
  let isLogged: boolean =  this.loggedInCustomer.isLoggedIn();
  if (!isLogged) {
    console.log(state.url);
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.env.getLoginUrl(), { queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
      return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

i've checked state.url it is correct. So the problem may be in creating router url.

I have made temporary solution

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`${this.env.getLoginUrl()}?returnUrl=${state.url}`);
```

here is a link to similar problem
[Setting router queryParams in angular 2 do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621581/setting-router-queryparams-in-angular-2-do-not-work)

But i know that it is not good. Can you please explain to me what am i doing wrong with this query? Why it stopped working? Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NavigateByUrl` is always absolute [Angular Doc's](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl). Instead you can use `navigate`:

```
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { 'returnUrl': state.url },
      fragment: 'anchor'
    };

    this.router.navigate([this.env.getLoginUrl()], navigationExtras);
```